# $c \in C \setminus R$ third unity root, $z \in C$. If $|z - 1| \le 1$ and $|z - c| \le 1$, then $|z| \le 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math, absolute-value

Let $c \in C \setminus R$ a third root of the unity. If $a \in C$ and $|z - 1| \le 1$ and $|z - c| \le 1$, then prove $|z| \le 1$. This problem was taken from a Romanian mathematical magazine. I have solved $c ^ 3 = 1$, with $c \in C \setminus R$ and got $c = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$. I tried dealing with the second inequality involving $z$ anc $c$, but I couldn't get anywhere. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Fix $a_i \in \mathbb C$.  You can see the following fact by drawing a picture:  if $\abs{a_1} = \abs{a_2}$, then the circles of radius $\abs{a_i}$ centred at $a_i$ intersect at $0$ and $a_1 + a_2$, and the intersection of the corresponding discs is contained in the circle of radius $\abs{a_1 + a_2}$ centred at $0$.

Here's an algebraic proof, which shows that we don't even need $\abs{a_1} = \abs{a_2}$ for the second part:  If $\abs{z - a_i}^2 = \abs z^2 - 2\Re(\overline{a_i}z) + \abs{a_i}^2 \le \abs{a_i}^2$, then $\abs z^2 \le 2\Re(\overline{a_i}z)$, so $2\abs z^2 \le 2\Re((\overline{a_1 + a_2})z) \le 2\abs{a_1 + a_2}\,\abs z$.  That is, $\abs z \le \abs{a_1 + a_2}$ (either because $\abs z \ne 0$ and we divided, or because $\abs z = 0$ and it's obvious).

Now apply this with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = c$.

Comment: I think there is a problem. $|z - a_i| ^ 2 = |z| ^ 2 - 2\Re (a_i z) + |a_i| ^ 2$ is false. Shouldn't it be $|z - a_i| ^ 2 = |z| ^ 2 - 2\Re (z\bar a_i) + |a_i| ^ 2$?

Comment: Oops!  Yes, you are [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983348/c-in-c-setminus-r-third-unity-root-z-in-c-if-z-1-le-1-and-z/3983382#comment8219589_3983382).  The rest of the argument goes through after making that change.